# Hp probook 4530s running on Ubuntu 14.04 overheats and lags

Tags: 14.04, hp, overheating

I've dual operating system in my Laptop(`hp probook 4530s`). `windows 7` with `Ubuntu 14.04`. `Windows` runs normal but the machine overheats when running `Ununtu`.
`lshw` command spits out a lot of information and I am confused looking at it. What are the possible causes of the overheating and laggy performance of ubuntu in my laptop. And how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem on my laptop HP Compaq nx8220 with Kernel 3.13.0-24 to 3.13.0-30 (in Ubuntu 14.04 and Linux Mint 17). This laptop ran Ubuntu and now Mint since 8 years without overheating problems. Try to boot from an older Live-DVD or USB stick with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS or Linux Mint 13. If this will fix your CPU fan then a bug in kernel 3.13.x might cause the problem.

I was able to fix it today with a pre-release of kernel 3.13.0-32 from https://launchpad.net/~canonical-kernel-team/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

**Careful users should wait a few days to get this fixed kernel as a normal update!**

From what I have read the problem was a kernel patch called "ACPI / AC: convert ACPI ac driver to platform bus" which has now been reverted in kernel 3.13.0-31 and higher.